# Windows 10 shows English and Japanese as languages, but refuses to switch between them

Tags: windows-10, language

I have a windows 10 pro x64 (22H2 build 19045.2604) install with both "English (Canada)" and "Japanese" languages installed, and while previously using <kbd>left-alt</kbd>+<kbd>left-shift</kbd> would show the language selector overlay and switch between languages, now the same key combination still *shows* the overlay:

[image]

But it does not cycle between the languages, and keeping <kbd>left-alt</kbd> pressed to keep the overlay up, and then clicking on the Japanese entry with the mouse does nothing. The language stays set to "eng" in the taskbar.

I've tried to search both superuser and the web but every article is about "how to make the keyboard shortcut work at all", which is rather different from my problem, where the keyboard shortcut clearly initiates the language switcher just fine, but the actual switching itself doesn't work.

I did uninstall Japanese, rebooted, added it back in, rebooted, to see if that'd fix the problem, but it hasn't. I also tried adding a third language in the form of US English, which gets added, and alt-shift *can* switch between US and Canada English, but will still refuse to select and activate Japanese, and clicking it with the mouse also does not activate it.

In terms of language and locale information, the main language is "English (Canada)" with the following options screen:

[image]

Japanese has the following options screen:

[image]

And my "Welcome screen and new user account settings" information under the control panel's "Region" looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this partially-broken language selector?

Comment: Try removing one of the other languages and reinstalling it.  Choose the language that wasn’t the language of the installation that was used.  I am making this suggestion since I don't know what the default language is.  You should provide that information.  You might also post the screenshot of your system locale information.

Comment: The default language in Windows 10 is the one shown at the top of the list in the overlay (which mirrors the ordering in the Time & Language "language" settings page). I've added and removed additional languages, which did not change anything about the behaviour when added, nor when removed again. I'd be happy to post system locale information, but that's not a name for any specific setting page in Windows 10, what settings page would you like to see a screenshot of?

Comment: It's "Region" within Control Panel, specifically, the "Welcome screen and new user account settings" window. I assume you are running 22H2? What I notice is you have the Microsoft IME installed, you don't actually have, the Japenese language pack installed (which would include the keyboard).

Comment: Cheers, added the screens. And yes, this is the 22h2 version (added that too). The Japanese language pack is installed, though, but the only option under "add a keyboard" is the Microsoft IME.

Comment: Looking at my Japanese options, see what happens if you add your (non Japanese) keyboard within your Japanese Language Options. Also check your Windows Settings Language > Keyboard settings, that's where the switching settings are. Off topic but I recommend a Japanese keyboard, they all have language switching keys. You set your input to Japanese in Windows and change to English on the keyboard negating language switching shortcut combinations completely.